# Errors connecting to MySQL database from alternate domain

Tags: php, mysql

I have two domains on two separate servers, `foo.com` and `bar.com`.

I have a website and MySQL database setup on `foo` that I want to migrate to `bar`, but `bar` doesn't have MySQL.

As a solution, I'm moving all the files across but leaving the database on `foo`, and connecting to it remotely.

I'm currently connecting like so:

**connect.php**

```
$hostname = 'database.foo.com';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$dbname   = 'database';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
}
```

This works fine on `foo.com` but when I migrate this file to `bar.com` I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'database.foo.com' (110)

I can have the two sites, `foo.com` and `bar.com` open in two windows, and one will work while the other doesn't - despite the fact that they are both connecting (or trying to connect) to the same database.

Why is this happening and how can this be rectified?

Comment: Domains don't matter. Are they the same server? If not, usually you can't just connect to databases from wherever. Your hosting service is the best place to ask.

Comment: I am very sure that your host provider has close for remote access

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen They are on separate servers - is there a workaround, or is the only route to contact the hosting provider?

Comment: Since opening the MySQL server to the broad internet is a security risk, they will likely deny your request.

Comment: Nope, if you only have shared access, there is no way to change this. In theory you could write an api on foo.com and call it from bar.com, but it probably makes a LOT more sense to just pony up a few pennies any pay for decent hosting in the 1st place

Comment: Thank you for your help. Why the downvote? I don't know the answer, does that make it an unreasonable question?

Comment: You will have to handle it with the hoster. You do not want to start playing with workarounds, they will just hurt you.

Comment: You need to allow the domain bar.com, from foo's cpanel>databases>remote mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database server is not configured to listen on a network port accessible to the other server.

There are several reasons why this might be.

It is typical to only listen on local sockets and not use TCP/IP at all since that is more efficient and secure.

The port might be firewalled off from the other machine.

The server might only be accessible on the local network and `foo.com` might be a different network with no route from `bar.com` to `database.foo.com`.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have database on server B and website on server A(say it has IP 192.234.23.12)

on cpanel whitelist the IP of server B

and create a new user having sufficient privileges in database (say this user is test)

then create this user as test@192.234.23.12

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the Remote MySQL access on **foo.com** by going to,
foo's cpanel > databases > remote mysql, and adding the **bar's** domain to white list it.
That should work.